# Robocopy "Documents" folder issue?

Tags: windows-10, backup, robocopy

I have a custom script I use for backing up my hard drive to a temporary external drive.  It's a simply a number of robocopy lines (without /PURGE).  I've having trouble with the windows documents folder.  If I have a command: "robocopy C:\users\me\documents D:\backups\somerandomdirectoryname ..", every time it's done, Windows thinks that directory is a Documents directory and even renames "somerandomdirectoryname" to "Documents".  It changes the icon, and then I can not actually eject the USB drive because Windows will not let it go.  What is causing Windows to do this to me?  Is there something I have to exclude to make it "just a normal directory" on my external device?

Comment: Never figured out an answer to this... must a just a standard windows "thing" and is not changeable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a cure to this, use the option:

```
/XA:SH
```

which stops copying system and hidden files - which are how the special attributes of the Document directory appear to be copied.  Worked for me, I only wanted the data files.